# AngularJS - Update another value inside watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I am trying to update a value in my nav.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" ng-controller="LoginController as login">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#/foo">Show option '{{login.showOption.show}}' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></li>
      <li ng-if="login.showOption.show" dropdown>
          <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
            Options <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a ng-href>1</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href>2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The `{{login.showOption.show}}` is referring to this controller

```
'use strict';
(function (module) {

  var LoginController = function (basicauth, currentUser, growl, loginRedirect, Option, $modal, $log) {
    var model = this;
    model.showOption = Option.value;
  };

  module.controller("LoginController", ['basicauth', 'currentUser', 'growl', 'loginRedirect', 'Option', '$modal', '$log', LoginController]);

}(angular.module("civApp")));
```

**The Option service**

```
'use strict';
(function (module) {

  var option = function () {
    var value = {
      show: false
    };

    return {
      value: value
    };

  };

  module.service("Option", option);

}(angular.module("civApp")));
```

**When the value of hasAccess changes, I want the nav.html also to either show or not show**

```
'use strict';
(function (module) {
var GameController = function ($log, $routeParams, GameService, PlayerService, currentUser, Util, Option, $filter, ngTableParams, $scope, growl, $modal) {
  var model = this;

  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return GameService.getGameById(model.gameId);
  }, function (newVal) {
    if (!newVal) {
      return;
    }
    var game = newVal;
    $scope.currentGame = game;

    var hasAccess = game.player && game.player.username === model.user.username && game.active;
    $scope.userHasAccess = hasAccess;

    Option.value = {
      show: hasAccess
    };
    //$scope.apply() <-- fails
    return game;
  });


};

  module.controller("GameController",
    ["$log", "$routeParams", "GameService", "PlayerService", "currentUser", "Util", 'Option', "$filter", "ngTableParams", "$scope", "growl", "$modal", GameController]);

}(angular.module("civApp")));
```

**But the problem is that nothing happens. I think its because I am inside a watch, and I need to either use apply or digest, but I don't know how!**

Here is link to the code

The code is here: 
https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame/blob/feature/options/civilization-web/app/scripts/controllers/GameController.js

https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame/blob/feature/options/civilization-web/app/scripts/controllers/LoginController.js

and

https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame/blob/feature/options/civilization-web/app/views/nav.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your service is returning false every time, you need to change your service like below.

And one more thing you are mixing up service writing pattern with factory pattern ([**Reference link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory/28262966#28262966)), here the code will look like below.

**Service**

```
'use strict';
(function(module) {

    var option = function() {
        this.value = {
            show: false
        };

        this.getValue = function() {
            return this.value;
        };

        this.setShowValue = function(val) {
            this.value.show = val;
        };
    };

    module.service("Option", option);

}(angular.module("civApp")));
```

**Controller**

```
Option.value = {
  show: hasAccess
};
```

will replace by

```
Option.setShowValue(hasAccess);
```

And while get the value object you could either use `Option.getValue();` or `Option.value`

& for `show` value you could do `Option.value.show`

Help this could help you, Thanks :-)

Comment: I wish this worked, but it doesn't. My nav.html still shows {{login.showOption.show}} as false even if I explicitly set `Option.setShowValue(true);` in my GameController.js

Comment: No nothing. You got to love Angular for that :(

Comment: @ShervinAsgari you should add this line `model.Option = Option;'in controller & on view like `<li ng-if="login.Option.value.show" dropdown>` OR `<li ng-if="login.Option.getShowValue()" dropdown>`

Comment: Thanks! That finally did it! I don't understand why though :)